# Publish live stream using webrtc and wowza

Tags: ssl, webrtc, wowza

I have taken a preview copy for webrtc. On my streaming server I have setup the streamlock and done with configuration in vhost.xml file. I'm unable to publish stream from the html files provided by wowza.

I get error: `Refused to set unsafe header “Connection”`.  I have added the hostport for port 443.

Answer (score 0):

The "Refused to set unsafe header "Connection", is not an issue. With the later package this is commented out.

Please comment out the below to remove the "Unsafe Header Connection" errors in your debug console

```java
//http.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", params.length);
//http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
```

I recommend double checking your configuration with the Readme that came with the WebRTC package.

Answer (score 0):

Host the html files in the wowza it self by using the stream lock jks file

Hosting example HTML over HTTPS

Host the HTML examples on your own web server that's secured using HTTPS. To install, copy the contents of the html folder to your web server.
Host the HTML examples on Wowza Streaming Engine using the built-in HTTPProviderSimpleWebServer HTTP Provider by doing the following:

Edit [install-dir]/conf/VHost.xml and add the following HostPort entry to the HostPortList (replace [streamlock-filename] and [streamlock-password] with your StreamLock filename and password):

```
<HostPort>
  <Name>Admin WebRTC</Name>
  <Type>Admin</Type>
  <ProcessorCount>${com.wowza.wms.TuningAuto}</ProcessorCount>
  <IpAddress>*</IpAddress>
  <Port>9443</Port>
  <HTTPIdent2Response></HTTPIdent2Response>
  <SSLConfig>
    <KeyStorePath>${com.wowza.wms.context.VHostConfigHome}/conf/[streamlock-filename].jks</KeyStorePath>
    <KeyStorePassword>[streamlock-password]</KeyStorePassword>
    <KeyStoreType>JKS</KeyStoreType>
    <DomainToKeyStoreMapPath></DomainToKeyStoreMapPath>
    <SSLProtocol>TLS</SSLProtocol>
    <Algorithm>SunX509</Algorithm>
    <CipherSuites></CipherSuites>
    <Protocols></Protocols>
  </SSLConfig>
  <SocketConfiguration>
    <ReuseAddress>true</ReuseAddress>
    <ReceiveBufferSize>16000</ReceiveBufferSize>
    <ReadBufferSize>16000</ReadBufferSize>
    <SendBufferSize>16000</SendBufferSize>
    <KeepAlive>true</KeepAlive>
    <AcceptorBackLog>100</AcceptorBackLog>
  </SocketConfiguration>
  <HTTPStreamerAdapterIDs></HTTPStreamerAdapterIDs>
  <HTTPProviders>
    <HTTPProvider>
      <BaseClass>com.wowza.wms.http.HTTPProviderSimpleWebServer</BaseClass>
      <RequestFilters>webrtc*</RequestFilters>
      <AuthenticationMethod>none</AuthenticationMethod>
    </HTTPProvider>
  </HTTPProviders>
</HostPort>
```

Create the folder [install-dir]/htdocs/webrtc and copy the contents of the html folder into this folder.
When using Wowza Streaming Engine to host the example files, use the following URL to access them: https://[streamlock-domain-name]:9443/webrtc/[path-to-example-file].

For example, if the StreamLock domain name is 123456.streamlock.net, the URL for the publish HTML example would be: https://123456.streamloack.net:9443/webrtc/publish/index.html.

Also if its in the aws EC2 server Open the ports in the security group

TCP - 9443,443

UDP - 6970 - 65535